# Configure HikariCP in Slick 3

Tags: slick

I have a project with that is using [Slick 3.1.0](http://slick.typesafe.com/) with [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) as the JDBC driver. When I enable connection pooling, which is using [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP), I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: JDBC4 Connection.isValid() 
   method not supported, connection test query must be configured
```

So for SQL Server the SQL query would be `SELECT 1`. **My question is: When using Slick, how do I set properties for HikariCP?** Is there some property to set in the config file? I tried the following to no effect:

```
jtds {
  driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://foobar.org:1433/somedatabase"
  user = "theUser"
  password = "theSecretPassword"
  properties {
    connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution to my own question. The HikariCP properties just go straight into the config file. For example, the solution to setting the connection test query was:

```
jtds {
  driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://foobar.org:1433/somedatabase"
  user = "theUser"
  password = "theSecretPassword"
  connectionTestQuery = "SELECT 1"
}
```